# Sigmoid shaped function with fixed start of ascent, and tunable slope

Tags: functions

I am looking for the simplest sigmoid function that goes from 0 to 1 and has a fixed starting point and tunable slope. As I am not a mathematician, I am sure I already used a lot of improper terms, but I hope it will be clear:

1. $$y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x\alpha}}$$

The standard sigmoid (1.) is not such, as it's starting position depends on the slope (α).

I found that (2.) has the desired start:

2. $$y=1-\frac{1}{\left( 1+\left( x \right)^{4} \right)}$$

[image]
[Plot image](https://snag.gy/zyhevW.png)

Now that is great, but I need a sigmoid, when below 0 (or actually below β in 3.) it is always zero and it is possibly differentiable.

3. $$y=1-\frac{1}{\left( 1+\left( x-β \right)^{4} \right)}$$

My most sincere apologies if this question breaks the noob-o-meter. 
Please also correct me, if I used the wrong terms/ language.

Comment: snaggy seems not that compatible with this site.

Comment: Sorry, I realised the `.jpg` needs to be replaced to `.png` to be working! Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Would you settle for a piecewise-defined function? A common way to build a “tunable” sigmoid is out of pieces of parabolas.

Comment: Piecewise, in my understanding is a set of two functions, evaluated on adjacent intervals. (Correct me if I am wrong.) I would avoid piecewise functions, if possible. 

I got to a certain point:

$${y=\left( 1-\frac{1}{\left( 1+α \cdot (x-β)^{4} \right)} \right)\cdot \left( .5+\frac{x}{2\cdot \mbox{abs}\left( x \right)} \right)}$$

where α tunes the slope and β tunes the inflexion point, but `abs()` is not differentiable, and I hope there is a simpler formula than above.

Comment: Which can be simplifed to:

 $$y= {0.5*(sgn(X) +1) \cdot α \cdot X^4 \over α \cdot X^4 +1}$$ 

where $$X=x-β$$ `sgn(x)` is differentiable at all values except `x=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently developed a sigmoidal function that is based on the [Superparabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superparabola) as a differentiable model for the Heaviside step function. It has the following attributes:

1. It is complete in a finite regime (i.e., the ends are absolute rather than asymptotic).
2. It is fully differentiable over the entire regime.
3. Parametrically, it can vary between a ramp function and a step function.

In addition, it can be moved and scaled as required. Without any further ado, the function is given by

$$f\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[ 1+\text{sgn} (x)\,\frac{B\left( {1}/{2}\;,p+1,{{\left| x \right|}^{2}} \right)}{B\left( {1}/{2}\;,p+1 \right)} \right]$$

where the numerator and denominator $B$s are the incomplete and complete beta functions, respectively. When $p=0$ you get the ramp function and as $p\to\infty$ you get the step function. For all other $p$ you get a sigmoidal function with variable rise slope.

Also, note that the derivative of the incomplete beta function is given by

$$\frac{d}{dx}B(\nu,\mu,x)=x^{\nu-1}(1-x)^{\mu-1}$$

The figure below shows a typical sigmoidal function so-calculated (red) and the superparabola (blue) from which it was created by integration.

[image: Sigmoid function]

Answer (score 2):

A simpler function that may be useful as a sigmoid function with tunable slope $m$ and range $[-1,1]$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ is
$$
f(x) = \frac{m x}{1+|x|(m-1)}
$$
This function is odd, i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$, and interpolates smoothly between $-1$ and $1$ for $x\in[-1,1]$, such that $f'(x)>0$, and $f'(0)=m$. When $m=1$, you get the ramp function (i.e., $f(x)=x$), and when $m\to\infty$ you get the Heaviside function. Note, however, that the slope at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ is not zero (impossible if you want to have the ramp function as one member of this family).