# What formula should I use for nonlinear mapping a value?

Tags: calculus

I want to map a time (0 to about 100.000 seconds, in ms) to a byte [0 to 256):

```
f(x) = ???

where 0 <= x    <= 100,000
      0 <= f(x) <= 255
```

Of course I will lose some accuracy, however I want the values between around 0.5 to 10 seconds to lose less accuracy than other values. So I want e.g. between 0.5 and 10 seconds to be mapped to e.g. 30 to 220 and (like in the picture below).

The function should look more or less like the picture below.

What should I put in the question marks  of the formula to get a similar function as the graphic?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402641/307825) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it (I found Desmos so I can play with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course many, many ways of coming up with this kind of function. An important tool for crafting curves with desired shape/slope are *splines*; in particular I recommend looking into [Hermite splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) (and Catmull-Rom splines).

Comment: I will look into it (if I can understand), thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: It looks like the most accurate way to go, but after checking this and simpler options, I go for a fixed table (mostly because of performance).