# How to approximate a sigmoid function, given the two points on x which correspond to where the curve stops at its y min and y max

Tags: curves, transformation

[image: Demostration of what I'm talking about]

Given a sigmoid equation  `L / ( 1 + e ^ (-kx - m))`

How can I determine "k" and "m" given inputs "x1" and "x2" (see picture)?

Where "x1" corresponds to the start of the "sigmoid curve" section, and "x1" corresponds to its end.

I'm just looking for approximation here, as long as f(x1) - f(x2) represents 90% of the amplitude or 99% of the amplitude or something similar to that, I will be happy.

I'm not sure if the ends of a sigmoid are asymptotes? If so then I would say that abs(f(x1) - f(x2)) should be equal to about 95% of the amplitude (L).

Comment: I have solved this exact problem previously. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402641/sigmoid-shaped-function-with-fixed-start-of-ascent-and-tunable-slope/2403818#2403818.